# Closed curve and a radical vector field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the curve r(t) = (2cos(t),  2sin(t), 2sin(t)+3)  for t between 0 and 2pi. I also have a vectorfield F=(x, y, x)

The lineintegral I get from r and F returns 0. But F is not conservative and r is a closed curve.

My question is therefore, is that right? I saw that if F is conservative and r is a closed curve, then the line integral is 0.

Comment: Just a general note: if you find a closed path such that a vector field $F$ integrates to zero over that closed path, this does not imply $F$ is conservative. This must hold for **all** paths in order for $F$ to be conservative.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I thought too, but got a little confused by another definition